# How to install JavaFX on Windows 10 Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I was trying some instructions I found on the internet, but they are too old to be of use now with the latest Eclipse IDE release.

The code I am trying to run:

```
package javafxbasics;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ShowFlowPane extends Application
{
  @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Create a pane and set its properties
    FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();
    pane.setPadding(new Insets(11, 12, 13, 14));
    pane.setHgap(5);
    pane.setVgap(5);

    // Place nodes in the pane
    pane.getChildren().addAll(new Label("First Name:"), 
      new TextField(), new Label("MI:"));
    TextField tfMi = new TextField();
    tfMi.setPrefColumnCount(3);
    pane.getChildren().addAll(tfMi, new Label("Last Name:"),
      new TextField());
    
    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene = new Scene(pane, 200, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("ShowFlowPane in Java FX"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
  }
  
  /**
   * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
   * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

> Error: Unable to initialize main class javafxbasics.ShowFlowPane in module JavaFXproject
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Stage

Comment: Use Java 8 for starting

Comment: Don't you think it makes more sense to start with the official documentation instead of grabbing some arbitrary stuff from the internet? https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a video how to do that: [How to Set Up JavaFX to work in Eclipse 2020 version](https://youtu.be/bC4XB6JAaoU)

That guy is a superhero. A couple of points:

1. when you download and unzip the latest JavaFX SDK for Windows release from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/, copy the location of that folder on your hard drive, you will need it to set up the path to the lib folder inside that package.
2. Here is the code which you will need to paste for the path:
   **--module-path "your path to \javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml**

As of 03/11/2020 solution works with Eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Build id: 20200910-1200 and javafx-sdk-15.0.1

Comment: And why does it need a video to find that out? This is clearly documented here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

Comment: ...Because I don't need to spend HOURS on reading a manual when I could do everything in 15 minutes just from watching the video and following the steps on the screen. I am not an engineer or a senior developer, all I need is to have JavaFX to be installed in my Eclipse for my Java course in the shortest way.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a build tool like maven or gradle. Those tools are usefull to manage dependencies like javafx in your case.

Overwise, you can follow instructions here for Eclipse: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ (link has instructions also for maven and Gradle).

Comment: Those instructions are not for Windows, unfortunately.

Comment: This is not true. Mostly they are generic and in the cases where they are specific you can switsh between two tabs (Linux/Mac and Windows)

Comment: Maven/Gradle are quite OS-independent. Instructions for Eclipse include Windows as @mipa said. I don't think you can have more detailed instructions.

Comment: I followed the instructions and got the error "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found"

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bk28ytggz7E

This works for me using this shorter version of YouTube as of 2021.

1 Install JavaFX from Eclipse MarketPlace

2 Download and install JavaFx

3 In Eclipse, add User Library to point to the folder path of JavaFx in step 2